# \autoref and linguex

Tags: hyperref, linguex

I use the `linguex` package for linguistics examples, and I'd like to be able to refer to the examples with the `\autoref` command. This works great for examples with labels:

```
\ex. \label{example} Hi.
```

In `\autoref{example}`, I wrote an example.

In a very long piece of work, I've primarily been referring to examples using `\Next` and `\Last`, rather than labels. Is there a simple way to link the `\Next` and `\Last` references using linguex and the `hyperref` package? Thank you!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

The counter is `ExNo`, then the name for `\autoref` can be defined the following way:

```
\newcommand*{\ExNoautorefname}{Example}
```

`\Next` and friends call `\printExNo` to print the example number, thus it can be redefined to add the anchor (assuming default options of `hyperref` regarding links):

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\printExNo}{%
  \@ifnextchar[{\complexExNo}{%
    \hyperlink{ExNo.\thetmpaEx}{%
      \if@noftnote\theExLBr\else\theFnExLBr\fi
      \thetmpaEx
      \if@noftnote\theExRBr\else\theFnExRBr\fi
    }%
    \xspace
  }%
}
\makeatother
```

Comment: Thank you! That's very helpful. Is there an easy way to modify this so that it will also link \Last[a], etc?

Comment: @Teresa Unhappily this is much more complicate, because also the anchor setting need to be changed to get better anchor names for `\autoref`. Thus it would be more or less a rewrite of the package `linguex`.